# MATLAB loop through certain integers and in the order that I specify v2

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, imread

The normal loop is

```
   for i=1:50

   end
```

but I want to execute the loop through certain integers in 4 different array simultaneously and in the order that I specify. So in the first loop, Matlab would take the first integer from r1, r2, c1, c2. Then for the second loop, Matlab would take the second integer from r1, r2, c1, c2.

```
For r1 = [1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128, 1128];
    r2 = [1148, 1148, 1148, 1148, 1148, 1148, 1148, 1148];
    c1 = [776, 776 + 1280, 776 + 1280*2, 776 + 1280*3, 776 + 1280*3 + 994, 776 + 1280*4 + 994, 776 + 1280*5 + 994, 776 + 1280*6 + 994, 776 + 1280*7 + 994];
    c2 = [792, 792 + 1280, 792 + 1280*2, 792 + 1280*3, 792 + 1280*3 + 994, 792 + 1280*4 + 994, 792 + 1280*5 + 994, 792 + 1280*6 + 994, 792 + 1280*7 + 994];
    a1_raw = imread('T:\SST\...\pinhole_1-8_6s', 'PixelRegion', {[r1, r2], [c1, c2]});
End
```

Also, I'd like a1_raw to change every time the loop loops so that at the end of the loop I should have 8 different "a1_raws". How can I do that in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a single index for all arrays

```
n = numel( r1 ); %// assuming r2, c1 and c2 all have same number of elements
a1_raw = cell( 1, n ); %//pre-allocate
for ii = 1:n
    r1i = r1(ii);
    r2i = r2(ii);
    c1i = c1(ii);
    c2i = c2(ii);
    a1_raw{ii} = imread('T:\SST\...\pinhole_1-8_6s', 'PixelRegion', {[r1i, r2i], [c1i, c2i]});
end
```

Comment: Cool, this works! Cheers Shai. The only thing is the "a1_raw" - by putting it like you have, I think I lose the 17x21 matrix I'd like it as. So in the end, I'd like 8 different variables, each referring to a 17x21 matrix. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I've worked out it:
`dataset = imread('T:\SST\...\pinhole_1-8_6s.tif', 'PixelRegion', {[r1i, r2i], [c1i, c2i]}); 


    eval(['a_raw' num2str(ii) '=dataset'])`